# IEnumWbemClassObject returning null in C++

Tags: c++, com

I was trying to read the Creation Class Name Property of Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray class but on running the code below the IEnumWbemClass object named enumerator was returning null. I am not able to figure out the problem. I would be very thankful  if anyone could help me out.

This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{


    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    IWbemLocator *locator;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemAdministrativeLocator, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, reinterpret_cast< void ** >( &locator ));
    IWbemServices * service;
    hr=locator->ConnectServer((BSTR)L"root\\cimv2", NULL, NULL, NULL, WBEM_FLAG_CONNECT_USE_MAX_WAIT, NULL, NULL, &service);
    IEnumWbemClassObject * enumerator;
    hr = service->ExecQuery((BSTR)L"WQL", (BSTR)L"SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray", WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY, NULL, &enumerator);
    ULONG retcnt;
    IWbemClassObject * memdevice;
    hr = enumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1L, &memdevice, &retcnt);
    variant_t var_val;
    hr = memdevice->Get(L"CreationClassName", 0, &var_val, NULL, NULL);
    cout << var_val.bstrVal;

    CoUninitialize( );
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the error:

[nullptr Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWy7G.png)

Note: There is a reason why i have not used CComPtr<> here. Whenever i was including that an assert faliure was being reported in the header file **atlcomcli.h**. I think this error might also be due to the nullptr exception of enumerator object. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the return code from `service->ExecQuery`.

Comment: I ran this code and the returned error is a variant of insufficient privilege, try running the code elevated.

Comment: Error checking is not optional, you have to verify with FAILED(hr).  Also the only way to know why this code fails, hr contains the error code.  Casting a string literal to (BSTR) is not correct, SysAllocString() or a smart pointer type is required.  Use the [MSDN sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390421(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: The issue is resolved. I checked the return code  Phil was right.  The problem was due to less previledge as mentioned by Soronel.  The code by Hans was very helpful.  It solved my problem.  Thanks guys.  Very happy that there are such developers like you guys

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue myself. The main problem was that of setting the required previledges for accessing. This was the reason why enumerate was returning a null pointer. To solve the issue write the following code immediately after making a call to CoinitiallizeEx:

MSDN sample from comments or

[Making WMI Queries in C++](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10539/Making-WMI-Queries-In-C)

Moreover as a note the above code must not be run by anyone in this way. This is because these pointers may leak memory if not used properly or an exception occurs.  Rather 
**atlbase.h**
And 
**Iwbemdl. h**
must be added to use CComPtr (Com Pointer class )  that will manage the construction and destruction automatically.